# Big Omega with negative coefficients

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I have a general question about the Big Omega and the Big O Notation. And yet I have to solve the following task:

```
Prove : n³ + 2n^2 - 5n - 10 ∈ O(n³) 
and n³ + 2n^2 - 5n^2 - 10 ∈ Ω (n³).

With the Big O notation I came to the following result:
n³ + 2n^2 - 5n - 10 <= c* n³
=> n³ + 2n^2 - 5n - 10 <= n³ + 2n³ - 5n³ - 10n³ = -12n³

-12n³ <= c*n³ | : n³ 
-12 <= c
```

Well, how do I have to go about the omega notation now? I can't get any further at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have run into trouble in this step:

> n<sup>3</sup> + 2n<sup>2</sup> - 5n - 10 ≤ n<sup>3</sup> + 2n<sup>3</sup> - 5n<sup>3</sup> - 10n<sup>3</sup>

For starters - is this true? If I plug in n = 10 into the left-hand side, I get 1,140. If I plug n = 10 into the right-hand side, I get -12,000, and it's definitely not the case that 1,140 ≤ -12,000.

The issue here is that while it is true that 5n ≤ 5n<sup>3</sup> for any natural number n, it is not the case that -5n ≤ -5n<sup>3</sup> for all natural numbers n.

If you're trying to find an upper-bound on your expression and you want to get rid of those pesky negative terms, consider instead just using the fact that -5n ≤ 0 and that -10 ≤ 0. You can, for example, say that

> n<sup>3</sup> + 2n<sup>2</sup> - 5n - 10 ≤ n<sup>3</sup> + 2n<sup>2</sup>.

Do you think you can take things from there?

Comment: Yeah, I think I get it. Now I could say yes: 

n³ + 2n2 - 5n - 10 ≤ n3 + 2n³ = 3n³            
3n³ <= c*n³ | :n³                
and 3 <= c        

So this would be my upper bound. Accordingly -12 my lower barrier, right?

Comment: Remember that you can pick totally different constants c and n_0 in your proofs for big-O and big-Omega. They don't need to be the same. In fact, you might want to name them differently - maybe c_o and n_o0 for big-O proofs and c_omega and n_omega0 for the big-Omega proof. What choices would you pick for those constants.

Comment: I would say: c_o = 3 and n_o0 >= 1, c_omega = 1 n_omega0 = 1.. correct?

Comment: You might want to double-check your math on the Omega proof. Is is true that n^3 + 2n^3 - 5n - 10 >= 1n^3 for all n >= 1?

Comment: Oh, absoloutly not. But I don't know how I can solve it now. I think, I don't really know how to do it.